# Kendo UI Gantt chart not processing JSON

Tags: php, json, kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

I've tried to switch the datasource of the Kendo UI Gantt example inside PHP. I have mapped the schema with what is being returned, but I just get a blank gantt chart with one heading - "undefined".

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": "1",
    "orderId": "1",
    "title": "TESTER1",
    "start": "\/new Date('2016-01-01 09:00:00')\/",
    "end": "\/new Date('2016-02-01 00:00:00')\/",
    "project": "1",
    "client": "4218",
    "parent": "0",
    "percentComplete": "10.11"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "2",
    "orderId": "2",
    "title": "TESTER2",
    "start": "\/new Date('2016-01-03 09:00:00')\/",
    "end": "\/new Date('2016-02-01 00:00:00')\/",
    "project": "1",
    "client": "4218",
    "parent": "0",
    "percentComplete": "50.00"
  }
}
```

Above is the JSON being sent back to Kendo, but it doesn't render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

I type casted the integers, set parents to null rather than zero (0) and converted dates into milliseconds in the PHP layer before putting through to Kendo. I also removed the keys which resulted in the below JSON to be created. This solved my rendering problem.

```
    [{
    "id": 1,
    "orderId": 1,
    "title": "TESTER1",
    "start": "\/Date(1463126400000)\/",
    "end": "\/Date(1463958000000)\/",
    "project": 1,
    "client": 4218,
    "parent": null,
    "percentComplete": 10
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "orderId": 2,
    "title": "TESTER2",
    "start": "\/Date(1463990400000)\/",
    "end": "\/Date(1464130800000)\/",
    "project": 1,
    "client": 4218,
    "parent": null,
    "percentComplete": 50
}]
```